# Automatically concat several JavaScript files in one?

Tags: javascript

I have many js files, with some naming convention. If there any tool that concatenate all this files in one, so I don't need to include them all separately ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with automatically? On build? Pre deployment? On page request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using a JS Minifier, like:

1. http://code.google.com/p/minify/
2. http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/
3. http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$> cat file1.js file2.js ... > allfiles.js
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
for file in `ls *js` ; do cat "$file" >> outputscript.js; echo >> "$file"; done;
```

Comment: `echo >> outputscript.js` possibly, don't see the point of adding a newline to the old files

Answer (score 0):

You might find some helpful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390/best-practices-for-managing-and-deploying-large-javascript-apps). Several answers advocate creating multiple javascript files during development, just so developers don't go crazy scrolling through thousands of lines of code. Those files are then merged during deployment -- several approaches are suggested. Several respondents also advocate using minification, which can reduce the size of the resulting mega-file.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the straightforward answers like using `cat` or a minifier, you can also use [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/), which is a JavaScript build system written in Ruby. Prototype JS uses Sprockets (in fact it Sprockets was written for Prototype).